# Unknown kind of view

Tags: ios5, view

i'm trying to show a custom view just after my app launching like this one.

[image: Custom view]

I don't know what kind of view to create, and how implement it exactly that way

Thanks in advance

Comment: If that is not a UIWebView loaded from Google via HTTPS it is a mean case of phishing...

Comment: I think it's case of pushing, because there's many application which do the same thing (Facebook sharing via ShareKit for exemple ).

Comment: there seem to be some related questions here. Search for "iOS modal login view"

Answer (score 0):

[KGModal](https://github.com/kgn/KGModal) may be a good start.

As the developer says :

> KGModal is an easy drop in control that allows you to display any view in a modal popup. The modal will automatically scale to fit the content view and center it on screen with nice animations!

Here is a screenshot :

[image: KGModal]